# Google Calendar API - How to save/use StoredCredentials?

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

The task is to save the stored credential file contents to database.

I am using the Google Java client quickstart project to get calendar and events from google. I am also using the offline access flag and set it as true. In the startup code it uses this:

```
.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
```

So instead of this FileDataStoreFactory can we use something else, so that I can write the contents to my database

Full code : https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample

I wanted to understand if I can save this StoredCredential file contents to the database for each user, so that I can schedule this calendar sync.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not good practice to store your users' credentials in a database. Instead, you should use a service account with domain wide delegation that will enable you to access your domain users' calendars without their credentials: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Thank you for the link @ziganotschka. If I understand this correctly, I should be looking into server-to-server oauth-2.0, right ? 
I have to sync the user's calendar events to my database. Can I achieve this using the link that you sent?

Comment: If the users are from your domain -  you can. I can provide you an answer with a basic workflow how to set-up and programmaticaly implement a service account.